# as.Date() without mentioning "origin"

Tags: r, date

I just started coding in R with the objective of avoiding if-else statements. I am trying to find a leap year and wrote the below code:

```
 leap <- function(year) {
 as.Date(year)
 return(
   gettextf("Year %Y is a leap year", ifelse(leap.year(year),year, "Year %Y is not a leap year"))
 )
}
leap(2019)
```

I explicitly want to omit origin as I want to find any leap years across the calendar.

Also, please advise if this works.

Comment: Change the first line of your function to `year <- as.Date(paste0(year, "-01-01"))`. Also, from which package is the `leap.year` function?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify an origin, you need to pass `as.Date` a character string. There are more issues with your code. This works:

```
library(lubridate)
leap <- function(year) {
  #don't forget to assign like this: 
  year <- year(as.Date(paste0(year, "-01-01"))) 
  
  #you need to nest your functions correctly:
  sprintf(ifelse(leap_year(year), 
                  "Year %d is a leap year", 
                  "Year %d is not a leap year"), 
           year)
 }

leap(c(2000:2020))
#[1] "Year 2000 is a leap year"     "Year 2001 is not a leap year" "Year 2002 is not a leap year"
 #[4] "Year 2003 is not a leap year" "Year 2004 is a leap year"     "Year 2005 is not a leap year"
#...
```

Comment: Hi Roland, Seems the solution is working only for years A.D. How can this be applied to Years B.C

Comment: There were no leap years BC. Back then a different calendar was used.